# dhcpd multiple domain-name-servers

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp-server

I know it's possible to assign at least two DNS servers via DHCP. For example:

```
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 4.2.2.2;
```

But I wanted to know if I could also add a third DNS or if this would even make sense?
My idea is to have a third DNS as a backup.

Can I do this or should I write my dhcpd.conf via a script that checks if the primary DNS are up.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Didn't come here for the answer you wanted. I just needed to correct syntax for multiple DNS servers. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/bootp/option006.htm) for option type 6 has variable length and can support more than two entries.  The length field is 8 bits and represents the number of bytes.  256 / 4 = 64 IP's.  Clearly this is well beyond the number that the client must recognize, but specifying 3 entries is likely supported by many clients.  It certainly won't hurt anything.  orst-case the client will ignore the third.

Whether it makes sense or not is a function of your own infrastructure and availability.  A WAN site might have two redundant servers on site and a third remote, for example.  There are a number of mechanisms to improve availability of DNS infrastructure, many of which don't require additional IP's to be configured on the client side (i.e. anycast, load balancers).

Answer (score 1):

you can put in as many as you want. 2 is common, 3 is not unreasonable and also somewhat common. 4+ would be edging in to overkill.